# How to describe your feelings when someone else is treated unfairly?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

For example, your female colleague experienced discrimination at work. You 'feel for her', and you're mad at the injustice in the system too.

It's more than that you feel sorry for her-- on top of that, I'm looking for a word that conveys the anger and frustration you empathetically share with her.

Comment: ***Vicarious indignation***. ***Secondhand umbrage***.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would likely describe your ***sympathetic*** response as, "**righteous indignation**."

> **RIGHTEOUS** *adjective*:
>
> **1**. (*of a person or conduct*) morally right or justifiable; virtuous. "he is a good, *righteous* man, I am sure"
>
> *synonyms*: good, virtuous, upright, upstanding, decent; see Google [**righteous**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=righteous+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=righteous+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.4.1646758...........0.FaVyzr_I_3U&gws_rd=ssl)
>
> **INDIGNATION** *noun*: anger or annoyance provoked by what is perceived as unfair treatment. "the letter filled Lucy with *indignation*"
>
> *synonyms*: resentment, umbrage, affront, disgruntlement, displeasure, anger, outrage, annoyance, irritation, exasperation, vexation, offense, pique. see Google [**indignation**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=indignation+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: Upvote. But is there any way to specify the indignation is due to the unfair treatment meted out to _someone else_ rather than you?

Comment: I believe that will require more words.  :-)

Comment: Yeah I think I have to go with `sympathetic indignation` (two words :) ). But I still can't think of an adjective that will do the job, as in "I feel (possibly an adverb here) __ for" the wronged person.

Comment: "sympathetic and righteous indignation." How's that, ladiesman?

Comment: "indignation" is what I first thought of.  +1